# xmlns attribute missing for element when marshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

Currently xml generated after marshalling which is missing the xmlns attribute for ColumnAlias:

```
<ns5:Environment xmlns:ns2="http://www.analytixds.com/amm/xml/systemmanager/v1/extendedproperties" xmlns:ns3="http://www.analytixds.com/amm/xml/systemmanager/v1/columns" xmlns:ns4="http://www.analytixds.com/amm/xml/systemmanager/v1/tables" xmlns:ns5="http://www.analytixds.com/amm/xml/systemmanager/v1/environments">
    <ns4:Tables version="12">
        <ns4:Table>
            <ns3:Columns version="12">
                <ns3:Column>
                    <ColumnAlias></ColumnAlias>
```

I am trying to set xmlns attribute for ColumnAlias Element so that output would be

```
<ns5:Environment xmlns:ns2="http://www.analytixds.com/amm/xml/systemmanager/v1/extendedproperties" xmlns:ns3="http://www.analytixds.com/amm/xml/systemmanager/v1/columns" xmlns:ns4="http://www.analytixds.com/amm/xml/systemmanager/v1/tables" xmlns:ns5="http://www.analytixds.com/amm/xml/systemmanager/v1/environments">
    <ns4:Tables version="12">
        <ns4:Table>
            <ns3:Columns version="12">
                <ns3:Column>
                    <ColumnAlias xmlns="http://www.stuff.com"></ColumnAlias>
```

My Domain class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Column")
public class Column {


    @XmlElement(name = "ColumnAlias", required = true,namespace="http://www.stuff.com")
    protected String columnAlias;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the xml that was being produced was also valid wrt to the schema and did not need the extra xmlns="http://www.stuff.com".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's common that namespace="http://www.stuff.com" must add namespace to its parent element "Column" and appropriate prefix to child element "columnAlias".